# Average By key in Python/Spark

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I am trying to do average based on key and I have been provided data as below:

```
data = [
    {"x":10,"y":30},{"x":20,"y":40}
]
```

So far tried

```
df=sc.parallelize(data)
df.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:sum(x)/len(x)).collect()
```

I am getting an error :

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 5 in stage 17.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 5.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 141, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):

Expected output :

```
 {"x":15,"y":35}
```

As we are averaging by key  `x` has `10` and `20` as values, `10+20/2 =15` ie `x:15` and `y` becomes `30+40/2=35` ie `y:35`

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 165, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
data = [
    {"x":10,"y":30},{"x":20,"y":40}
]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: (line.items())).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x : sum(x)/len(x)).collect()

dict(val)

{'x': 15.0, 'y': 35.0}
```